# XML reading and writing to Excel using VB.Net

Tags: excel, xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I am completely new with XML operations in VB. I am very much confused with child nodes, attributes, XElements. I tried few ways using XElements it is showing empty values, am not successful. Please help me in this. :(

I have this sample code in ".arxml" file.
I need to iterate the `CLUSTER` and get the `SHORT-NAME` (Note - In this there is only one cluster, but it might vary).

Under the one Cluster's "`SCHEDULE-TABLES`, there will be `CON-SCHEDULE-TABLE`. 
For each `CON-SCHEDULE-TABLE` I need `SHORT-NAME`, `DELAY`, `TRIGGER` values which are under `table-entrys` > `application-entry`s.

I need respective `CON-SCHEDULE-TABLE` values to be written in one row of Excel.

I need to write the details which is read from XML to Excel sheet as below which will contain the header as

**Context**

Sample Excel rows:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TEST-ID | CLUSTER-SHORT-NAME | CON-SCHEDULE-TABLE-SHORT-NAME  | DELAY  |  TRIGGER 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1      |  LIN-1             |     DIAG1                      |  0.01  |  M_LIN
                                                              |  0.11  |  M_LIN_1

 2      |                    |     RUN_MAIN                   |  0.01  |  M_LIN_01

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```xml
   <?XML version = '1.0’ encoding='UTF-8'?>
<AUTOSAR xmlns=http://autosar.org>
   <AR-PACKAGES>
     <AR-PACKAGE>
       <SHORT-NAME>System</SHORT-NAME>
      <AR-PACKAGES>
         <AR-PACKAGE>
            <CLUSTER>
                <SHORT-NAME>LIN-1</SHORT-NAME>
                <LIN-CLUSTER-VARIANTS>
                    <LIN-CLUSTER-CONDITIONAL> 
                       <BAUDRATE>19200</BAUDRATE>
                       <PHYSICAL-CHANNELS>
                          <LIN-PHYSICAL-CHANNEL>
                             <SHORT-NAME>M_LIN_9</SHORT-NAME>
                             <ADMIN-DATA/>
                             <FRAME-TRIGGERINGS>
                                <FRAME-TRIGGERING>
                                    <SHORT-NAME>M_LIN_01</SHORT-NAME>
                                    <IDENTIFIER>60</IDENTIFIER>
                                    <CHECKSUM>ENHANCED</CHECKSUM>
                                </FRAME-TRIGGERING>
                                <FRAME-TRIGGERING>
                                    <SHORT-NAME>M_LIN_01</SHORT-NAME>
                                    <IDENTIFIER>60</IDENTIFIER>
                                    <CHECKSUM>ENHANCED</CHECKSUM>
                                </FRAME-TRIGGERING>
                             </FRAME-TRIGGERINGS>
                             <SCHEDULE-TABLES>
                                <CON-SCHEDULE-TABLE>
                                    <SHORT-NAME>DIAG1</SHORT-NAME>
                                    <RESUME-POSITION>START-FROM-BEGINNING</RESUME-POSITION>
                                   <TABLE-ENTRYS>
                                      <APPLICATION-ENTRY>
                                           <DELAY>0.01</DELAY>
                                           <TRIGGER>M_LIN</TRIGGER>
                                     </APPLICATION-ENTRY>
                                    <APPLICATION-ENTRY>
                                        <DELAY>0.11</DELAY>
                                        <TRIGGER>M_LIN_1</TRIGGER>
                                   </APPLICATION-ENTRY>
                             </CON-SCHEDULE-TABLE>
                           <CON-SCHEDULE-TABLE>
                              <SHORT-NAME>RUN_MAIN</SHORT-NAME>
                             <RESUME-POSITION>START-FROM-BEGINNING</RESUME-POSITION>
                             <TABLE-ENTRYS>
                                  <APPLICATION-ENTRY>
                                      <DELAY>0.01</DELAY>
                                     <TRIGGER>M_LIN_01</TRIGGER>
                                  </APPLICATION-ENTRY>
                                 <APPLICATION-ENTRY>
                                     <DELAY>0.01</DELAY>
                                    <TRIGGER>M_LIN_02</TRIGGER>
                                 </APPLICATION-ENTRY>
                             </TABLE-ENTRYS>
                        </CON-SCHEDULE-TABLE>
                        <CON-SCHEDULE-TABLE>
                             <SHORT-NAME>RUN_MAIN</SHORT-NAME>
                            <RESUME-POSITION>START-FROM-BEGINNING</RESUME-POSITION>
                           <TABLE-ENTRYS>
                               <ASSIGN-FRAME-ID-RANGE>
                               <DELAY>0.01</DELAY>
                               <ASSIGNED-SLAVE-CONFIG>SAMPLE</ASSIGNED-SLAVE-CONFIG>
                               <FRAME-IDS>
                                  <FRAME-ID>
                                     <INDEX>0</INDEX>
                                  </FRAME-ID>
                                    <FRAME-ID>
                                     <INDEX>0</INDEX>
                                  </FRAME-ID>
                               </FRAME-IDS>
                            </ASSIGN-FRAME-ID-RANGE>
                            <ASSIGN-FRAME-ID>
                                <DELAY>0.01</DELAY>                       
                                <TRIGGER>M_LIN_03</TRIGGER>
                            </ASSIGN-FRAME-ID>
                            <ASSIGN-FRAME-ID>
                                <DELAY>0.01</DELAY>                       
                                <TRIGGER>M_LIN_03</TRIGGER>
                            </ASSIGN-FRAME-ID>
                          </TABLE-ENTRYS>
                       </CON-SCHEDULE-TABLE>
                       <CON-SCHEDULE-TABLE>
                         <SHORT-NAME>RUNEVENT</SHORT-NAME>
                         <RESUME-POSITION>START-FROM-BEGINNING</RESUME-POSITION>
                         <TABLE-ENTRYS>
                            <APPLICATION-ENTRY>
                               <DELAY>0.02</DELAY>
                               <TRIGGER>M_LIN</TRIGGER>
                            </APPLICATION-ENTRY>
                         </TABLE-ENTRYS>
                       </CON-SCHEDULE-TABLE>
                     </SCHEDULE-TABLES>                    
      </LIN-PHYSICAL-CHANNEL>


                      </PHYSICAL-CHANNELS>
                    </LIN-CLUSTER-CONDITIONAL>


                </LIN-CLUSTER-VARIANTS>

         </AR-PACKAGE>
     </AR-PACKAGES>
     </AR-PACKAGE>


   </AR-PACKAGES>

Please find the script which i have tried for the logic

Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class frm_HexGen
    Private Sub Button1_Click1(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim str_File_Name = “Schedule.xlsx”
        Dim str_File_Template As String
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlSH As Excel.WorkSheet
        Dim myRange As Excel.Range

        Dim Current_Directory As String

        Current_Directory = CurDir()

        str_File_Template = Current_Directory&”\_log”&str_File_Name

        xlWB=xlApp.Workbooks.Open(str_File_Template)
        xlApp.Visible=True
        xlApp.ActiveWindow.WindowState=XlWindowState.xlMaximized

        xlSH=xlWB.Worksheets(“Sheet1”)
        xlSH.Activate

        If NOT My.Computet.FileSystem.FileExists(str_File_Template) Then
            MsgBox(“error”)
        End If

        Dim iRow As Long = 2

        Dim bOK As Boolean
        Dim OXMLDOC As Object=Nothing

        oXMLDOC=CreateObject(“Microsoft.XMLDOM”)
        bOK=oXMLDOC.Load(“board.xml”)

        If not bOK Then
            MsgBox(“failed to load”)
        End If

        Dim nodes1,nodes2,nodes3,nodes4,nodes5
        Dim nodes1,node2,node3,node4,node5

        Dim str_Frame_Trigger As String = “”
        Dim str_Frame_Trigger_Name As String()
        Dim str_Trigger_Name As String
        Dim str_Length As Integer
        Dim str_Frame_Name As String
        Dim str_Identifier As Integer

        nodes1=oXMLDOC.SelectNkdes(“//CLUSTER”)

        For Each node1 In nodes1
            For Each node2 In node1.ChildNodes
                If node2.tagName =”SHORT-NAME” Then
                    iRow = iRow+1
                    xlSH.Cells(iRow,2)=node2.Text
                ElseIf node2.tagName = “LIN-CLUSTER-VARIANTS”
                    nodes3 = node2.SelectNodes(“//LIN-CLUSTER-VARIANTS/LIN-CLUSTER-CONDITIONAL/PHYSICAL-CHANNELS/LIN-PHYSICAL-CHANNEL/SCHEDULE-TABLES/SCHEDULE-TABLE/*)
                    For Each node3 in nodes
                        If node3.tagName=”SHORT-NAME” Then
                        testID = testID+1
                        xlSH.Cells(iRow,1)= testID
                        xlSH.Cells(iRow,3)= node3.text
                ElseIf node3.tagName=”Table-Entrys” Then
                    node4=node3.SectNodes(“(APPLICATION-ENTRY|ASSIGN-FRAME-ID|ASSIGN-FRAME-ID-RANGE)/*)
                    For Each node4 In nodes4
                        If node4.tagName = “DELAY” Then
                        If not Is nothing(xlSH.Cells(iRow,4) Then iRow=iRow+1
                        xlSH.Cells(iRow,4)=node4.text
                ElseIf node4.tagName = “TRIGGER” Then
                If not Is nothing(xlSh.Cells(iRow,5) Then iRow=iRow+1
                str_Frame_Trigger= node4.Text

                nodes5=node2.SelectNode(“//LIN-CLUSTER-VARIANTS/LIN-CLUSTER-CONDITIONAL/PHYSICAL-CHANNELS/LIN-PHYSICAL-CHANNEL/FRAME-TRIGGERINGS/FRAME-TRIGGERING/*)
                For Each node5 In nodes5
                    If node5.tagName=”SHORT-NAME”
                        str_Frame_Name=node5.Text
                        If str_Frame_Name = str_Frame_Trigger Then
                            str_Identifier = node5.tagName(“IDENTIFIER”).text
                            xlSH.Cells(iRow,6)=str_Identifier
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next

            End If

        Next
        iRow=iRow+1

    End If
Next

        End If
    Next

Next




    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Just to be clear.  You want to read xml from some source, then parse it and save the output as a formatted Excel spreedsheet?

Comment: Ya I need to read the XML the particular values mentioned and write to the excel sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in the XML which show up in Firefox

```
XML Parsing Error: XML declaration not well-formed
Location: file:///C:/temp/autosar.xml
Line Number 1, Column 22:
<?xml version = '1.0'encoding = 'UTF-8'?>    
---------------------^

XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </TABLE-ENTRYS>.
Location: file:///C:/temp/autosar.xml
Line Number 24, Column 26:
                   </CON-SCHEDULE-TABLE>
-------------------------^
```

If you fix those this might work for you

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class frm_HexGen
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSH As Excel.Worksheet

    Dim str_File_Name = "Schedule.xlsx"
    Dim str_File_Template As String
    Dim Current_Directory As String

    Current_Directory = "C:\temp" 'CurDir()
    str_File_Template = Current_Directory & "\_log" & str_File_Name

    If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(str_File_Template) Then
        MsgBox("Error - File not found " & str_File_Template, vbCritical)
    End If

    xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(str_File_Template)
    xlApp.Visible = True
    xlApp.ActiveWindow.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized

    xlSH = xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    xlSH.Activate()

    Dim header As String() = {"TEST ID", "AR-RANGE", "CLUSTER-SHORT-NAME", "CON-SCHEDULE-TABLE_SHORT-NAME",
        "DELAY", "TRIGGER", "TRIGGERING-INDENTIFIER", "TABLE-ENTRY"}
    xlSH.Range("A1:H1").Value = header

    Dim bOK As Boolean, sXMLFilename As String
    sXMLFilename = Current_Directory & "\" & "board.xml"
    Dim OXMLDOC As Object = Nothing

    OXMLDOC = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    bOK = OXMLDOC.Load(sXMLFilename)

    If Not bOK Then
        MsgBox("XML file failed to load : " & sXMLFilename, vbCritical)
    Else
        xlApp.StatusBar = "Loaded " & sXMLFilename
    End If

    Dim nodes0, nodes1, nodes2, nodes3, nodes5, nodesFT
    Dim node0, node1, node2, node3, node4, node5, nodeFT
    Dim sFTname As String = ""
    Dim sFTident As String = ""

    Dim iRow As Long = 0
    Dim testID As Integer = 0

    ' process each package
    nodes0 = OXMLDOC.SelectNodes("/AUTOSAR/AR-PACKAGES/AR-PACKAGE/*")
    For Each node0 In nodes0
        If node0.tagname = "SHORT-NAME" Then
            iRow += 2
            testID += 1
            xlSH.Cells(iRow, 1) = testID
            xlSH.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = node0.Text
        ElseIf node0.tagname = "AR-PACKAGES" Then
            nodes1 = node0.SelectNodes(".//CLUSTER/*")

            'process each cluster
            For Each node1 In nodes1
                If node1.tagname = "SHORT-NAME" Then
                    xlSH.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = node1.Text
                ElseIf node1.tagname = "LIN-CLUSTER-VARIANTS" Then
                    nodes2 = node1.SelectNodes(".//LIN-PHYSICAL-CHANNEL/*")

                    For Each node2 In nodes2
                        ' get frame triggering name and ident
                        If node2.tagname = "FRAME-TRIGGERINGS" Then
                            For Each nodesFT In node2.ChildNodes
                                For Each nodeFT In nodesFT.ChildNodes
                                    If nodeFT.tagname = "SHORT-NAME" Then
                                        sFTname = nodeFT.Text
                                    ElseIf nodeFT.tagname = "IDENTIFIER" Then
                                        sFTident = nodeFT.Text
                                    End If
                                Next
                            Next

                        ElseIf node2.tagname = "SCHEDULE-TABLES" Then
                            nodes3 = node2.ChildNodes
                            For Each node3 In nodes3
                                For Each node4 In node3.ChildNodes
                                    If node4.tagname = "SHORT-NAME" Then
                                        If Len(xlSH.Cells(iRow, 3).value) = 0 Then iRow += 2
                                        xlSH.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = node4.Text

                                    ElseIf node4.tagname = "TABLE-ENTRYS" Then
                                        nodes5 = node4.SelectNodes(".//(DELAY|TRIGGER)")
                                        For Each node5 In nodes5

                                            If node5.tagname = "DELAY" Then
                                                If Len(xlSH.Cells(iRow, 5).value) > 0 Then iRow += 1
                                                xlSH.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = node5.Text
                                            ElseIf node5.tagname = "TRIGGER" Then
                                                If Len(xlSH.Cells(iRow, 6).value) > 0 Then iRow += 1
                                                xlSH.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = node5.Text
                                                If node5.Text = sFTname Then
                                                    xlSH.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = sFTident
                                                End If
                                            End If
                                            xlSH.Cells(iRow, 8).Value = node5.ParentNode.tagname ' TABLE-ENTRY
                                        Next
                                    End If
                                Next
                            Next
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    xlApp.StatusBar = "Finished processing " & sXMLFilename
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: In this line "Set oXMLDOc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")"  getting 'Let' and 'Set' assignment statements are no longer supported.

Comment: I am able to assign objects or values without set property. But the a the delay and trigger values are getting displayed irrespective of particular " CON-SCHEDULE-TABLE". The node4.text for delay and trigger is showing all the delay and trigger values.  Can we able to loop according to the "CON-SCHEDULE-TABLE" respective values?

Comment: Ya, but for the "CON-SCHEDULE-TABLE" - RUN-MAIN, there is no application entry but delay and trigger values are there. How it will work for that cases? Can you please in it?

Comment: I have 3 possible ways where DELAY and TRIGGER values will displayed. (1) APPLICATION-ENTRY (2) ASSIGN-FRAME-ID-RANGE (3) ASSIGN-FRAME-ID.   As per your answer it is working for first case APPLICATION ENTRY. Is there any possible ways to check for FRAME-ID-RANGE and FRAME-ID under "TABLE-ENTRYS"

Comment: Thank you it is working. I need one more help please.  The text which am getting in this part "node4.tagName = “TRIGGER”, I need to compare in another part of the XML and get the value which belongs to "IDENTIFIER" Tag.  Please check the updated XML which I have kept in question . Under <FRAME-TRIGGERINGS><FRAME-TRIGGERING> I need to take the short name, if the short name is same as "node4.tagName = “TRIGGER""'s text I need to store the value of identifier under the FRAME-TRIGGERING.   I have written the logic under the elsif part. Please check and help me.

Comment: If there are more than one cluster it is iterating all "LIN-CLUSTER-VARIANTS", how to control it?

Comment: if there are more cluster it is iterating all "CLUSTER-VARIANTS" under each cluster and entering all table deatils for first cluster itself. How to control it

Comment: @AbarnaAbi I can't reproduce the problem. Check you have a dot at the start of the Xpath expression here - node0.SelectNodes(".//CLUSTER/*"). Delete some of your older  comments